# Is it okay to use the forward slash in informal dialogues?

Tags: informal-language, alternatives

Is it okay to use '/' in a dialogue of an informal story? If not, what is the alternative?

My sentence:

> They all wanted to come; to support you and/or to witness the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that the dialogue is informal? I'm not certain what you would mean by an informal story. In either case I would say it's fine if that's what the character is actually saying.

When speaking aloud some people might say "and/or" as "and or" and some people might say "and slash or". In text I would generally write the person saying "and or" as "and/or" so it's clear to the reader what they mean. I would leave "and slash or" as it is.

I have heard both of those used in somewhat formal contexts, but I think it's more of an informal construction. In, for example, a formal speech I would get around it by saying something like "to support you, to witness the event, or both".

Answer (score 1):

Style books usually advise against using ***and/or*** in formal writing, but it's perfectly natural in informal and/or spoken contexts. There's no really succinct "direct replacement" alternative - you'd have to rephrase to something like *...[either] to support you, [or] to witness the event, or [to do] both.*

<sup>transcribed from comment</sup>